# Can siblings(UK) with an Irish born parent submit their Irish passport applications at the same time, using the same original docs from their parent?

Tags: passport, documentation

Can siblings (residing in U.K) with an Irish born parent, use the same original documents, to submit applications for individual irish passports?  I am aware that we do not need to apply on the foreign births registration as we are automatically enrolled( if I am correct).
All help appreciated, Many Thanks.